# Are Guids guaranteed to be unique?

Tags: sql-server-2008, guid

I'm using Guids as primary keys in my database and was wondering if it is ever possible that a duplicate Guid might be generated.  Are Guids guaranteed to be unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> While each generated GUID is not guaranteed to be unique, the total
>   number of unique keys (2128 or 3.4×1038) is so large that the
>   probability of the same number being generated twice is very small.

You can check more info on that [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/nannettethacker/archive/2008/09/03/guids-unique-or-not.aspx).

---

**A possible solution** to avoid duplicate guids (if you still want one) is to use the [UNIQUE constraint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

While each generated GUID is not guaranteed to be unique, the total number of unique keys (2^128 or 3.4×10^38) is so large that the probability of the same number being generated twice is very small. For example, consider the observable universe, which contains about 5×10^22 stars; every star could then have 6.8×10^15 universally unique GUIDs.

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_Unique_Identifier).

Answer (score 1):

They are guaranteed to be unique if you use NEWSEQUENTIALID() to generate one. Still, Microsoft claims[1] that it will be unique and that

> no other computer in the world will generate a duplicate of that GUID
>   value.

Wikipedia states[2] that

> Microsoft added a function to the Transact-SQL language called
>   NEWSEQUENTIALID(),[8] which generates GUIDs that are guaranteed to
>   increase in value, but may start with a lower number (still guaranteed
>   unique) when the server restarts

In short: in practice, they're going to be unique.

[1] http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190215(SQL.105).aspx
[2] http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Globally_unique_identifier#Sequential_algorithms

Comment: **No they're not!** You still have a very slim chance of duplicates... each Guid produced by `NEWSEQUENTIALID()` is guaranteed to be unique **on that computer** only.....

Comment: @marc_s I assumed that this question was asked within the context of a single server. Still, I wouldn't call the chance of a duplicate ID ever happening on another computer AND it being relevant to your use case significantly less than "slim". Which is why I say that they're going to be unique in practice and I wouldn't dare advice against the use of GUIDs because they're 99,99999% guaranteed to be unique rather than 100%. :)